# Rails 3.2 current_password authentication failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, bcrypt, change-password

Using Ruby 1.9.3 and bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1

I'm working on the Depot app from the Agile Web Development book, and I'm having issues authenticating a user's current password in order for them to change their password.

My Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  after_destroy :ensure_an_admin_remains

  private
    def ensure_an_admin_remains
      if User.count.zero?
        raise "Can't delete last user"
      end
    end
end
```

My update method in the Users controller looks like this:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.authenticate(params[:current_password])
      params[:user].delete :current_password
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully updated." }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), notice: "Current password is incorrect."
    end
  end
```

My users form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter User Details</legend>
        <div>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40 %>
      </div>
        <% if params[:action] == :edit %>
            <div>
                <label for="old_password">Old Password:</label>
                <%= password_field_tag :current_password, params[:current_password]%>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <div>
        <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
      </div>
        <div>
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm' %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40%>
        </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

The issue seems to be with the `@user.authenticate(params[:current_password])` line.
I am puzzled, because I think the authentication is within the scope for the param, and also because this very method on the console does pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:current_password])`

Comment: This, along with modifying the form, did the trick. Instead of the current_password field above, I used the rails-generated form label and password field for :current_password.